# find the CURRENT first child of an element with jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've gotten great results from this website in the past(read: yesterday) and a contributer here created this: http://jsbin.com/awerep/1/edit. now I want to make the currently selected tab swap places with the first tab. i'm having difficulties understanding how to use Jquery's and Javascripts this and first-child selectors.  I'm going to be swapping around the menu items by cloning the first menu item, placing it before the clicked menu item, and replacing the first menu item with the clicked menu item. I think I can use jquery's this-child selector to determine the current first child of the wrapper. However, if the position of the elements change dynamically (due to replacewith), does it dynamically also update what the first-child is. Or will the first child still be element 1?

edit:
Thanks everyone for all the help. This is what I went with (being the first one to actually work the way I intended it to): http://jsbin.com/olojok/1

Comment: try it and find out!  Code is free to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want move selected tab to 1st place, then add this code to `.click()`

```
$(this).prependTo($(this).parent());
```

**EDIT**: If you want swap 2 tabs

```
var $firstTab = $('.menuitem:first');
var $clickedTab = $(this);

$firstTab.insertAfter($clickedTab);
$clickedTab.prependTo($clickedTab.parent());
```

Comment: This won't swap the place of the first and clicked element. It'll simply make the first element the second element.

Comment: It almost works. check out http://jsbin.com/eqigok/1/edit and click on the third tab. it swaps places with the second,but I can't see why.

Comment: you have typo in `prependto`, shoud be `prependTo`

Comment: If you click on the currently selected element, it disappears.

Comment: because IF shoud look like this `if (!$currenttab.is($firstmenu))`

Comment: but this has nothing to do with Question topic so select one of answers as right or ask what its not working regarding to question

Answer (score 0):

(In jQuery) `This` will always be the currently selected element. If you wish to select the first element from multiple elements that you may have selected, simply do `$('.elements')[0]` or `$('.elements:first-child')` or `$('.elements:nth-child(1)')`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you move an *existing* element it's just detached from the DOM and re-inserted in the right place, so you don't need to clone any elements.

You can use `.siblings().first()` to find the current element's first sibling, and `.insertBefore` to move that element in front of the current element.

You can then use `.prependTo()` to move the current element to the first position in the list.

```
function swapWithFirst(el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    $el.siblings().first().insertBefore(el);
    $el.prependTo(el.parentNode);
}
```

If there are no text nodes contained in the parent then the middle line can be replaced with:

```
$el.before(el.parentNode.firstChild);
```

Comment: if the function is called in an event handler, could i pass it _this_ (the element clicked on that created the event) via swapWithFirst(this)?

Comment: @user2472522 yes, something like that that should be possible.

Comment: Why doesn't this work? http://jsbin.com/adesoc/1/ It declares $parent to be the element that triggered the event's parent element, checks if the triggering element is the first element, if not it gets $parent's first child and sets it before the current element and then prepends the current element to the parentn ode, making it the first. Where did I mess up?

Comment: it's probably because of all those whitespace nodes I warned you about in the comments to one of the other answers.  You're also trying to call jQuery methods (e.g. `.insertBefore`) on raw HTML nodes, not jQuery objects.

Comment: The if seems broken, even if the clicked on tab is the currently selected tab it fades it and displays it again. Probably due to the whitespace nodes. Is there an easy way to determine if the first node is a whitespace node and move to the next sibling if it is?

Comment: @user2472522 ah, that just means that the animations need to be moved inside the `if`.  jQuery's `:first` selector ignores text nodes.

Comment: @user2472522 I don't know, then - seems a bit odd.  In any event, the swapping part works, and that was the scope of the original question.

Comment: @user2472522 the problem was the `.not(':first')` test - I replaced it with `$this.index() > 0` and it works fine.  I note that you're using my function but accepted the other answer?!